# exponent(power) prime of $n!$ in its factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove :if $n \in \Bbb N, n \gt 1 $then in factorization of $n!$ at least one prime number with exponent(power) of $1$ exist.

Comment: This is equivalent to the claim that there is a prime between $n$ and $n/2$ (include the upper end, but not the lower). A non-trivial but known fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :Look at the biggest prime  $<n$. And read Jyrki's comment to finish the proof.

Comment: if the biggest prime $p$ why power of $p$  is $1$?

Comment: If the power is greater than 1, $2p<n$ As there is a prime between p and 2p, p can't be the largest prime <n

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove this by using [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), which states that

for every $n > 1$ there is always at least one prime $p$ such that $n < p < 2n$.

Or in other words there is always a prime number $p$ in range $(\frac{n}{2},n]$, which guarantees that $p$ will have power $1$ in factorization of $n!$

Comment: why power of $p$ is $1$

Comment: because the next number which divides $p$ is $2p$ and we have that $p>n/2$ or $2p>n$